# How to a string can turn a UserControl

Tags: c#, asp.net, rendering, user-controls

Is there any ways/possibilities that I can replace a string with a UserControl?

apart from LoadControl and adding it to another control like page or placeholder.

The reason is that a user add a content on the page and put a string like {uc:test} and I would like to parse this text and replace {uc:test} with a UserControl.

in other words ; 
The user input will be "bla bla bla {uc:test} bla bla", when I retrieve it from database how can I inject usercontrol and replace it with {uc:test}

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the LoadControl method to dynamically load user controls and add them to your page during postback.

```
Control someControl = LoadControl("~/SomeControl.ascx");
```

You could... Add it to your page's control collection:

```
        this.Page.Controls.Add(someControl);
```

Or... Add it to another control's control collection

```
        someExistingPlaceHolder.Controls.Add(someControl);
```

How about getting the tags like this using regex

```
List<string> fields = new List<string>(); 
foreach(Match match in Regex.Matches(str, @"\{([^\}]*)\}")) { 
    fields.Add(match.Groups[1].Value); 
}
```

Comment: the user input will be "bla bla bla {uc:test} bla bla", when I retrieve it from database how can I inject usercontrol and replace it with {uc:test}

Comment: Using string manipulation to detect { and } to begin with, so string.IndexOf() to get positions for reserved tag then you can add "bla bla bla" as a literal control which will render as text, add the uc:test control, add "bla bla" as a literal control

Comment: After you get the string you can use stringName.Replace("{uc:test}", "_userControlHere_");

Answer (score 0):

If you want *all* of the user input to be respected, including any control references they've included, use [ParseControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kz3ffe28.aspx):

```
string markup = input.Replace("{","<").Replace("}",">");
Control control = this.Page.ParseControl(markup);

this.Page.Controls.Add(control);
```

This will create a new `Control` which represents all the text ("blah blah") as Literal child controls, as well as create new instances of `<uc:test>` as nested child controls.

Comment: ParseControl(@"bla bla bla <uc:test id=""xx"" runat=""server"" /> bla bla");... how do you register the control uc:test so that it is not an unknown server tag? I tried <%@ Register TagPrefix...> in an example but no luck.

Comment: When registered in web.config the control is found but does not render... the surrounding text does

Comment: @Boon have you tried adding that particular control to the page explicitly and see if it works correctly?